# IE compatible drag scrollable Div

Tags: javascript, datepicker, touch, iscroll4

Attached is a fiddle for a concept input similar to that found on the iPhone. Uses a library called iScroll4 that works on everything except IE.

I have tested IE 8 and IE 9 and both do not work. Here is a fiddle that will work Firefox, Chrome, Safari and touchscreen mobile devices.

http://jsfiddle.net/XHPYF/

Can any one solve it?

Answer (score 2):

iScroll have this problem for a long time. You need to update iScroll code manually to get it fixed. zyrex solution is Ok but can be better:

```
if(!document.addEventListener) {
        document.attachEvent('touchmove,', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
        document.attachEvent('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
    } 

    else {
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with 'do not work in IE'?

I encountered a problem, that my complete page does not load in IE when using iScroll. The error occured in eventListener.

I fixed it by switching the event listener if IE <= Version 8. And it worked.

```
if(getInternetExplorerVersion() != '-1' && getInternetExplorerVersion() <= '8') {
        document.attachEvent('touchmove,', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
        document.attachEvent('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
    } 

    else {
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
    }
```